# MBP16 charging: After sleep mode no charging (but with charging icon), restart helps

Tags: battery, sleep-wake, charging, power

I have strange charging behavior that started some time ago.
My MBP16 (Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101)) just stopped charging until i do some actions.

[!]ITS HAPPENING RANDOMLY, not all the times.

AND EACH CONNECTION OF POWER ADAPTER MAKES 'CHARGING' SOUND. :)

So my flow:

1. Going back from office -> home, connect the same charger, HEAR 'charging sound', wake up laptop. Sometimes it's charging, sometimes it's not (recently started having it).
2. Going to office from home, the same flow, the same results.

Charging icon is exist except the case the battery is running out.
Power settings says battery is ok (i bought it just some time ago), i'm using it with original power adapter.
And only restart macbook (or SCM sometimes) is helping me.
So it looks like after sleep mode it's not charged from time to time.
It really looks like software bug but i'm not sure, because i can see it's not charging, i don't touch/move any cables/adapter, just restart it - and it's fine.
The same ports, other ports, nevermind - just discharging with connected power AC until restart/reset.
So i'b doubt about "Defective battery/Defective charger" point.

Any ideas please? :(

Diagnostic test says - ADP000 (no issue).

```
system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -i "charge information" -A 10

      Charge Information:
          Charge Remaining (mAh): 8604
          Fully Charged: Yes
          Charging: No
          Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 8604
      Health Information:
          Cycle Count: 28
          Condition: Normal
      Battery Installed: Yes
      Amperage (mA): 180
      Voltage (mV): 12837
```

Just after MPB16 woke up. NO CHARGING.
[image: Just after MPB16 woke up]
Power settings
[image: Power settings]
Power settings with adapter part
[image: Power settings part that says adapter is connected]
After restart/smc. CHARGING.
[image: After restart or SMC reset]
Activity Monitor Energy tab
[image: Activity Monitor Energy tab]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109616/discussion-on-question-by-max-lukin-mbp16-charging-after-sleep-mode-no-charging).

Answer (score 1):

Apple hardware on 10.15.5 doesn’t charge batteries until they fall below a band so that they don’t always use a charge event when you’re mostly full.

This is intentional and documented fairly well.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211094

This appears to be entirely correct behavior unless I missed something major in your question. This feature is excellent in my testing and I strongly urge everyone to keep it enabled if they want their batteries to last as long as possible before they get exhausted and must be replaced.

Comment: There's no mention it's should be happened only after sleep mode and the charging process would be resumed after restart. :( Anyway, thanks.